# Iterate through list of dictionary and create new list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

My data is as follows.

```
[
    {
        "id" : "123",
        "type" : "process",
        "entity" : "abc"
    },
    {
        "id" : "456",
        "type" : "product",
        "entity" : "ab"
    }

]
```

I am looping though it as follows to get id and entity

```
for test in serializer.data:
    qaResultUnique['id'] = test['id']
    qaResultUnique['entity'] = test['entity']
    uniqueList.append(qaResultUnique)
```

but getting wrong output as only getting 2nd dictionary both times .

```
[
        {
            "id" : "456",
            "entity" : "ab"
        },
        {
            "id" : "456",
            "entity" : "ab"
        }

    ]
```

What I am doing wrong , please help.

Comment: both elements in the new list is the same dictionary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are reusing the `qaResultUnique` dictionary object. Create a *new* dictionary in the loop each time:

```
for test in serializer.data:
    qaResultUnique = {}
    qaResultUnique['id'] = test['id']
    qaResultUnique['entity'] = test['entity']
    uniqueList.append(qaResultUnique)
```

or more succinctly expressed:

```
uniqueList = [{'id': test['id'], 'entity': test['entity']} for test in serializer.data]
```

Answer (score 4):

As [@Martijn explained the actual problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22253086/1903116), you can actually do this with dictionary comprehension like this

```
keys = {"type"}
print [{k:c_dict[k] for k in c_dict if k not in keys} for c_dict in data]
# [{'id': '123', 'entity': 'abc'}, {'id': '456', 'entity': 'ab'}]
```

You can use this method to skip any number of `keys`, without having to change the dictionary comprehension part. For example, if you have to skip both `type` and `entity`

```
keys = {"type", "entity"}
print [{k:c_dict[k] for k in c_dict if k not in keys} for c_dict in data]
# [{'id': '123'}, {'id': '456'}]
```

Comment: Dictionary comprehension is only available in Python 2.7+.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify like this.

Before:

```
uniqueList.append(qaResultUnique)
```

After:

```
uniqueList.append(dict(qaResultUnique))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can always do it like following

```
for test in serializer.data:
    uniqueList.append({'id':test['id'],'entity':test['entity']})
```

or in list comprehension

```
uniqueList=[{'id':test['id'],'entity':test['entity']} for test in serializer.data]
```